# Git Scalar for managing many big files?

Tags: git, repository

"Plain" Git is not a good choice when a repository contains many big data assets (such as textures, 3D models, virtual environments, trained neural nets, audio files, etc.) for different reasons, such as:

- Fetch/clone speed goes down
- Users can probably not checkout the repo because of limited disk space (e.g. when repo is > 1 TB)

Nevertheless, it is desirable to be able to manage data and source code together in one repository.

There is Git LFS, but it has some drawbacks, e.g.:

- referenced files can get deleted by accident, since they are not part of the "real" repo
- misc git LFS issues, when switching between branches
- User sometimes forget to also check in Git LFS files
- No good migration path if reference files move later to another location (old commits will than point to invalid file locations)

Recently, Git [scalar](https://git-scm.com/docs/scalar) was added to Git.

I wonder if git scalar can solve the previous mentions issues. Currently, I use Perforce to manage my repo, since it seems the only version control system that can handle big files in the repo and has a decent support/community.

Does anyone here have experience with git scalar to manage a big mono repo with many big data assets?
Are there any preferable providers for such an setting? Has Azure good support for Git Scalar mono repos? Or does Scalar work only for small files (< 100 MB)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or give it a try?